# Have ImageView draw bitmap flipped horizontal?

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I have an ImageView and a bitmap. I want the ImageView to draw the bitmap mirrored horizontally. I'm trying to do it using a matrix, like so:

```
ImageView iv = ...;
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
iv.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
matrix.preScale(-1, 1);
iv.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

But the ImageView does not appear after using the above. If I comment out the above, it appears ok. How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might consider trying to flip the bitmap passed into the image view, rather than flipping the image view itself.  Here is an example:

```
public class Main extends Activity {
 ImageView imViewAndroid;
 public static final int FLIP_VERTICAL = 1;
 public static final int FLIP_HORIZONTAL = 2;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  imViewAndroid = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imViewAndroid);
imViewAndroid.setImageBitmap(flipImage(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.car),2));
 }
 public Bitmap flipImage(Bitmap src, int type) {
  // create new matrix for transformation
  Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
  // if vertical
  if(type == FLIP_VERTICAL) {
   // y = y * -1
   matrix.preScale(1.0f, -1.0f);
  }
  // if horizonal
  else if(type == FLIP_HORIZONTAL) {
   // x = x * -1
   matrix.preScale(-1.0f, 1.0f);
   // unknown type
  } else {
   return null;
  }

  // return transformed image
  return Bitmap.createBitmap(src, 0, 0, src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), matrix, true);
 }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't that require a new bitmap to be created? Wouldn't it be more performant to just have the graphics layer draw the same bitmap flipped?

Comment: Yes, this requires creating a new bitmap.  I haven't seen a solution (yet) where the creation of a new bitmap isn't required.

Answer (score 0):

This works, you need to offset by the width of the image after the flip:

```
ImageView iv = ...;
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.preScale(-1, 1);
matrix.postTranslate(iv.getLayoutParams().width, 0);

iv.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX); 
iv.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

Answer (score 0):

First get Bitmap from your Drawable like

```
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.car),2);
```

and then

```
public enum Direction { VERTICAL, HORIZONTAL };

/**
    Creates a new bitmap by flipping the specified bitmap
    vertically or horizontally.
    @param src        Bitmap to flip
    @param type       Flip direction (horizontal or vertical)
    @return           New bitmap created by flipping the given one
                      vertically or horizontally as specified by
                      the <code>type</code> parameter or
                      the original bitmap if an unknown type
                      is specified.
**/
public static Bitmap flip(Bitmap src, Direction type) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    if(type == Direction.VERTICAL) {
        matrix.preScale(1.0f, -1.0f);
    }
    else if(type == Direction.HORIZONTAL) {
        matrix.preScale(-1.0f, 1.0f);
    } else {
        return src;
    }

    return Bitmap.createBitmap(src, 0, 0, src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}
```